# Why can't I set AES KeySize in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cryptography, aes, encryption-symmetric

In the following function(C#), the default value of KeySize is 128, if i don't set any value into KeySize, this function can work fine, the encrypted result would be as same as what I prediceted. But if I set 128 into KeySize, which is as same as the default value, then the result would be unpredictable. I set same input data, but the result would changed each time. I really have no idea what's going on.(p.s. I also tried 192, still work as same situation.)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;    

private static byte[] AesEncrypt(byte[] keys, byte[] iv, byte[] data, int size)
{
    using Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create();
    aesAlg.Key = keys;
    aesAlg.IV = iv;
    if (size != 0)
    {
        aesAlg.KeySize = size;
    }
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
    using MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
    using CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    csEncrypt.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    byte[] encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
    csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
    return encrypted;
}
```

Comment: Your code is broken because you attempt to access the result before calling Flush. No idea what other problem(s) you're having, you haven't really described it well and there are multiple missing values we'd have to guess at to be able to run your code and *see what you're seeing*.

Comment: When you set the key size, a new key is implicitly created (replacing the old one), even if the key size is the same as that of the old key. However, it doesn't really make sense to set the key size after setting the key, because when setting the key, the key size is implicitly set.

Comment: I think that is fine for an answer, and it shows that the question really doesn't need to be closed. It would have been nice if the API failed though, instead of allowing the key size to be set. Generating a brand new key on setting `KeySize` fails the principle of least surprise in many ways.